# How to define the order of property deserialization when using ASP.NET Web API 2.2 OData V4

Tags: odata

I would like to define the order of property deserialization when using ASP.NET Web API 2.2 OData V4. Perhaps there is already an attribute which can be used to define this. For the purpose of this e-mail I name it DeserializationOrderAttribute. I imagine I should be able to define a class like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    [DeserializationOrder(0)]
    public Guid EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [DeserializationOrder(1)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DeserializationOrder(1)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

In this situation, the EmployeeID property should be deserialized before FirstName and LastName. FirstName and LastName can be deserialized in any mutual order.

Is there an attribute for achieving this or is there another standard way of achieving definition of the order of property deserialization?

Best regards,

Henrik Dahl

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [DataMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to your properties and then specify the [Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.order(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Note that properties not decorated with this attribute will always appear first as detailed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Actually, this does not seem to work. I have added a DataContract attribute to the class and DataMember attributes to the properties having an Order of either 0 or 1. The order of deserialization is however exactly the same as before and the DataMember's Order is not respected. It looks like the order is alphabetical order. In my real case Employee has a superclass for which I have also added a DataContract and also a KnownType attribute. It read "If a data contract type is a part of an inheritance hierarchy, data members of its base types are always first in the order.". This is not the case.

Comment: @HenrikDahl Which format do you get your data in, json or atom?

Comment: `DataMember` does not affect deserialization in OData, the order is determined by the order of the properties in the serialized content.